# How to immediatelly update Parent state inside Child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I'm trying to immediatelly update a parent components' state so I can properly use it in a Child (nested) component. I will try to give as many details as possible so you an understand.

So basically I have a parent component (**App.js**):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Child from "./Child";
import Modal from "./Modal";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([
    { Player: "Kevin Durant", Team: "Brooklyn Nets" },
    { Player: "LeBron James", Team: "Los Angeles Lakers" },
    { Player: "Michael Jordan", Team: "Chicago Bulls" }
  ]);
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState({});
  const [modalContent, setModalContent] = useState(null);
  const [show, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  const showModal = () => {
    setShowModal(true);
  };

  const hideModal = () => {
    setShowModal(false);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
        className="row"
        style={{
          justifyContent: "center",
          width: "100%",
          margin: "40px 0px 0px 0px"
        }}
      >
        <div
          className="table-cell other"
          onClick={() => {
            setModalContent(() => (
              <Child
                options={options}
                selectedOption={selectedOption}
                setSelectedOption={setSelectedOption}
              />
            ));
            showModal();
          }}
        >
          <div className="table-cell-text">Click to access Child component</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Modal
        show={show}
        modalClosed={hideModal}
        width={"40%"}
        title={"Choose a Player"}
      >
        {modalContent}
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**App.js** (**parent component**) visual:

[image]

This component has an array of objects (**options**) that is sent to the **Child** component as props.

Array of objects I mentioned:

```
  [
    { Player: "Kevin Durant", Team: "Brooklyn Nets" },
    { Player: "LeBron James", Team: "Los Angeles Lakers" },
    { Player: "Michael Jordan", Team: "Chicago Bulls" }
  ]
```

Basically the Child component has a Modal component and a select input, which will show the options.

**Child.js**:

```
import React from "react";
import Team from "./Team";

const Child = (props) => {
  return (
    <div style={{ position: "relative", margin: "0 auto", width: "10em" }}>
      <div className="input-group col">
        <select
          className="form-control"
          onChange={(e) => {
            let foundOption = props.options.find(
              (options) => options.Player === e.target.value
            );
            props.setSelectedOption(foundOption);
          }}
        >
          <option value="">Select a Player...</option>
          {props.options.map((option) => (
            <option key={option.Player} value={option.Player}>
              {option.Player}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
      <Team selectedOption={props.selectedOption} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Child;
```

**Child.js** visual:

[image]

The Child component also has a Team component. Basically the **Team** component receive the selectedOption as props and shows a div with the selectedOption.Team value.

**Team.js**:

```
import React from "react";

const Team = (props) => {
  console.log(props.selectedOption);
  return (
    <div style={{ marginTop: "30px" }}>
      Team:{" "}
      {props.selectedOption !== undefined ? props.selectedOption.Team : ""}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Team;
```

The thing is, if I select an option, the Team component doesn't receive the updated selectedOption immediatelly. So, if I want to show the players' team, I need to select an option, close the modal and reopen it again.

I also recorded a video to show the issue: https://youtu.be/3P1tURgxvTQ

I would like to know how can I make it work properly! If you guys don't understand my question, please let me know and I will try to improve it. Thank you all!

My CodeSandbox:

[image: Edit optimistic-browser-870oe]

Comment: Instead of using `useState` to control the content of the modal in addition to its visibility state, just render the modal's content (`<Child>`) and only control its visibility. This way, the content will be updated when the props change.

Comment: @cbr how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be your `App.js` file:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Child from "./Child";
import Modal from "./Modal";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([
    { Player: "Kevin Durant", Team: "Brooklyn Nets" },
    { Player: "LeBron James", Team: "Los Angeles Lakers" },
    { Player: "Michael Jordan", Team: "Chicago Bulls" },
  ]);
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(); // <--- remove the {} from here because your checking props.selectedOption !== undefined in Team Comp
  const [modalContent, setModalContent] = useState(false); // <--- the content state is now just a boolean
  const [show, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  const showModal = () => {
    setShowModal(true);
  };

  const hideModal = () => {
    setShowModal(false);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
        className="row"
        style={{
          justifyContent: "center",
          width: "100%",
          margin: "40px 0px 0px 0px",
        }}
      >
        <div
          className="table-cell other"
          onClick={() => {
            setModalContent(true);
            showModal();
          }}
        >
          <div className="table-cell-text">Click to access Child component</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Modal
        show={show}
        modalClosed={hideModal}
        width={"40%"}
        title={"Choose a Player"}
      >
        {modalContent && (
          <Child
            options={options}
            selectedOption={selectedOption}
            setSelectedOption={setSelectedOption}
          />
        )}
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This would be the `Child.js`

```
import React from "react";
import Team from "./Team";

const Child = (props) => {
  return (
    <div style={{ position: "relative", margin: "0 auto", width: "10em" }}>
      <div className="input-group col">
        <select
          className="form-control"
          onChange={(e) => {
            let foundOption = props.options.find(
              (options) => options.Player === e.target.value
            );
            props.setSelectedOption(foundOption);
          }}
        >
          <option value="">Select a Player...</option>
          {props.options.map((option) => (
            <option key={option.Player} value={option.Player}>
              {option.Player}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
      <Team selectedOption={props.selectedOption} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Child;
```

and this would be the `Team.js`

```
import React from "react";

const Team = (props) => {
  console.log(props.selectedOption);
  return (
    <div style={{ marginTop: "30px" }}>
      Team:{" "}
      {props.selectedOption && props.selectedOption.Team || ""}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Team;
```

Although I'm not quite sure why you keep the `options` as a state or why you need the `selectedOption` in `App.js`, it makes sense to put it in `Child.js`

Comment: Hello, Taghi! It is because in my project I'm using a similar layout and in the App.js I'm submitting a form (I'm using the selectedOption data to send as a post request), that is why I need the selectedOption to be in App.js

Comment: Thank you, Taghi! I would like to take the opportunity and ask you another question, if possible. I would like to know the theoretical reason why it wasn't working

Comment: @Polalas The reason for that was you were setting the `Child` Component as a state (`modalContent`) and the `modalContent state` which was `Child Component and its props` were only set when you clicked on the parent component (when you open the modal). that's why you had to close the modal and open it again to see the new `props` for the `Child` Component.